# JSON Loading Lazy properties

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities

Product:

```
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;

 private String name;

 private String description;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
 private Product parentProduct;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
 private Set<Product> childProduct;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonManagedReference @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
 private Set<Image> images;
```

Image:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String type;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JsonBackReference
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private Product product;
```

the lazy relationship are being loaded when I call from a RestController but when I call from my main method (Spring Boot) they came empty.

What I do to maintain lazy when Json serialize.

json return:

```
    [ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Passatempo Pacote",
  "description" : "Cookies Package",
  "images" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "type" : "png"
  }, {
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "jpeg"
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Passatempo",
  "description" : "Cookies",
  "parentProduct" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Passatempo Pacote",
    "description" : "Cookies Package",
    "images" : [ {
      "id" : 2,
      "type" : "png"
    }, {
      "id" : 1,
      "type" : "jpeg"
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

Images must be empty because lazy config on property

Answer (score 1):

The Json Serializer will call the get method, which will load your lazy field.
If you don't want these lazy field in json, you could annotate them @JsonIgnore.

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) means the field will be ignored only if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` instead of `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`.